# RTK query POST method does not mutate data

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am trying to fetch some data with RTK. GET method works properly. POST method also works but does not mutate data. I added provideTags and invalidateTags also for automatic refetch but still could not make it.

**this is my store**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 
import { verdeApiSlice } from "../features/verde/verde-slice"; 

export const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: {
    [verdeApiSlice.reducerPath]: verdeApiSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(verdeApiSlice.middleware);
  },
});

export const AppDispatch = store.dispatch;
export const RootState = store.getState;
```

**this is slice**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const verdeApiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "verdeApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Post"],
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      getPosts: builder.query({
        query: () => "/posts",
        providesTags: ["Post"],
      }),
      addPost: builder.mutation({
        query: (post) => ({
          url: `/posts`,
          method: "POST",
          body: post,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: ["Post"],
      }),
    };
  },
});

export const {
  useGetPostsQuery,
  useAddPostMutation,
} = verdeApiSlice;


export default verdeSlice.reducer;
```

**And that is how i call addPost method**

```
 const [addPost, { isLoading }] = useAddPostMutation();

 const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await addPost(post).unwrap();
      setPost(initialValue);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, that's normal. Those public mock apis accept POST requests, but they always return static data - they will never actually mutate.

Comment: It means there is no way to mutate data with rtk query right? I can do it using local state of redux

Comment: The point of RTK Query is to mutate data on the server and then get that new data back from the server. The server you are interacting with is not changing any data - because it is a mock server, nothing you would see in reality.